# In Postgres,Create View Using Join Condition

Tags: postgresql

I have calendar table with columns(id,agent_id,date,location) and agent table with columns(id,name,phone_number,email).
I need to create a view of calendar table with additional column(agent_email),where agent_email is  from agent table email column as same as agent_id in calendar table is id from agent table.

[image]

I have tried as in above screenshot,but instead of agent_email in
table column ,I have ?column?.

Comment: Can you post the actual SQL statements to create your tables?

Comment: @SebDieBln I have already created those both tables(calendar,agent)

Comment: Well, but I haven't. And I could only help you once I have :-)

Comment: You are looking for [a join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html)

Comment: @SebDieBln added screenshot . But this calendar,agent tables are created from backend

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you ,that I didn't know why shouldn't post code as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select calendar_events.*, agents.email
from calendar_events
left outer join agents on calendar_events.agent_id=agents.id;
```

This gives my expected answer ,

columns :

id | agent_id | date | location | agent_email